# React router parent layout renders

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I have a router with a layout inside of it. My problem is that on every route path change, the whole layout component re renders which it shouldnt. When a page changes only the new page should be loaded not the entire app.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          {routes?.map(props => {
            return <AuthProtectedRoute key={props} {...props} />;
          })}
          <Route component={404Page} />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The routes array that is mapped contains a list of the routes and their properties. The AuthProtectedRoute component just checks if the user is logged in else it redirects to login.
Also if someone can let me know if this is the proper way of using a shared app layout component by wrapping it in Route.

Comment: Why there's no `path` prop on your second route?

Comment: @BadalSaibo it is connected to any path. I wrapped it in a route because I read somewhere that the only children of a switch should be Routes